Remove lines when specific colums have the same value
I have this 16 columns file (tab separator) :
0/0;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/0;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/0;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20     0/1;20,20        0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20       0/1;20,20
0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/1;11,6        0/3;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/1;11,6      0/2;11,6 0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6
0/0;12,12       0/1;12,10       0/0;12,12       0/1;12,10       0/0;12,12       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10     0/1;12,10        0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10       0/1;12,10
0/0;43,43       0/1;43,44       0/0;43,43       0/1;43,44       0/0;43,43       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44     0/1;43,44        0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44       0/1;43,44
0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9        0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10     0/0;10,10        0/1;10,9        0/2;10,11       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9

I need to remove entire lines where the value in columns $2, $4 and $6 to the end $16 are equal, line by line. I simply use :
awk -F'\t' '!a[$2 $4 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10 $11 $12 $13 $14 $15 $16]++' test.txt 

But that still outputs all the lines. I should get only two lines, where I notice differences between the specified columns :
0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/1;11,6        0/3;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/1;11,6      0/2;11,6 0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6
0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9        0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10     0/0;10,10        0/1;10,9        0/2;10,11       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9

Any help?

just looking at $2 it is clear that all the lines have different values. Why do you think any of them are the same?

note that !a[k]++ removes duplicates - the first instance is always output

The first line for example should be removed because the values in the colums 2, 4, 6 -> 16 are the same, for line 1. I work only on the lines.

your current awk script is comparing the contents of different lines while your description suggests you're interested in comparing the contents of  different columns (within a given line)

you are right, I understand ; according to my conditions, I need to work line by line

GNU awk (plus some, but not all, awk flavors) can use the length() function to count the number of elements in an array.  We can make use of this feature of length() in this case ...
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

      { delete arr                      # clear array

        arr[$2]                         # use our list of fields to
        arr[$4]                         # create indices in
        for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) arr[$i]     # the array arr[]
      }

length(arr) != 1                        # number of elements (aka distinct indices)
                                        # is "== 1" if all columns have the same value;
                                        # "!= 1" implies there are different values
' test.txt

If your version of awk does not support the use of length() on arrays there are several ways to implement this feature in a custom function, eg:
awk '
function arr_length(_arr, i, count) {
    count = 0
    for (i in _arr)
        count++
    return count
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

      { delete arr
        arr[$2]
        arr[$4]
        for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) arr[$i]
      }

arr_length(arr) != 1
' test.txt

Another option (which should work in any flavor/version of awk) where we compare column values and if we find a difference then we print the current line:
awk '

function cmp_print(_val) {
    if (val != _val) { print; next }
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

      { val = $2
        cmp_print($4)
        for (i=6;i<=NF;i++)
            cmp_print($i)
      }
' test.txt

NOTE: for large(r) data sets the 3rd script should show better performance if simply because we don't have the overhead of repeatedly populating/deleting the arr[] array
All 3 scripts generate:
0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/1;11,6        0/3;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/1;11,60/2;11,6 0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6
0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9        0/0;10,10       0/0;10,100/0;10,10       0/1;10,9        0/2;10,11       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9


awk '
    BEGIN{
        split("4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16", c)
        for (i in c)
            a[c[i]]
        FS="\t"
    }
    {
        v2 = $2
        for (ci in a)
            if (v2 != $ci) {
               print
               break
            }
    }
' inputfile

Creating a is just to avoid double indirections on every test.

Thanks, interesting way to do.


remove entire lines where the value in columns $2, $4 and $6 to the
end $16 are equal

For brevity sake, let say that we want to remove lines where $2, $4 and $6 are equal. This could be expressed as follows
awk -F'\t' '!($2==$4&&$2==$6)' test.txt

Explanation: find lines where it is not (!) true that 2nd field value is equal (==) 4th field value and ($$) 2nd field value is equal (==) 6th field. As is equal is transitive if $2==$4 and $2==$6 then also $4==$6. Observe that this requires x-1 comparisons where x is number of columns to be equal. Thus it might not be best fit if your columns to be equal are not etched in stone.

This is not a final solution, but it can give you a start:
cat file1.txt | awk -F "\t" '{if ($2!=$4) print $0}'


Please keep in mind that GNU awk can read file on its own (no need to summon cat) and you might just specify condition to print lines where it holds i.e. {if ($2!=$4) print $0} is equivalent to $2!=$4

Using any awk:
$ awk -v OFS='  ' '{ o=$0; $1=$3=$5=""; n=gsub(" "$NF" ",""); $0=o } n != (NF-4)' file
0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/1;11,6        0/3;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/1;11,6      0/2;11,6 0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6
0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9        0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10     0/0;10,10        0/1;10,9        0/2;10,11       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9

Here's how that works:

-v OFS='  ' - set the OFS to 2 blanks so that after executing step 3 below there's always 2 blanks between fields so that at step 4 below there's always at least 1 blank before and 1 blank after each remaining field for the " "s in the regexp to match.
o=$0 - save the original value of $0 in a variable so we can modify $0 in steps 3 and 4 before restoring it in step 5 below.
$1=$3=$5="" - set the 3 fields we don't want to be part of our comparison to null strings and, since modifying any field causes awk to reconstruct $0 from it's fields while replacing all FSs with OFSs, put 2 blanks between all remaining fields. Note that this does not remove fields, it just sets the value of some fields to null and NF will still be 16.
n=gsub(" "$NF" ","") - replace all values that match $NF except the last one (as it doesn't have a blank after it) with nothing, returning the count of the number of times a field was replaced and saving that in n. If all the other remaining fields have the same value as $NF then this will return the count of all remaining fields minus 1, i.e. 12. This relies on none of the chars in $NF being regexp metachars, as is the case with the OPs sample input. We need to wrap $NF in blanks here to avoid false matches if some field exists that is not equal to $NF but $NF is a substring of it.
$0=o - restore $0 to its original contents which we saved in step 2 above.
n != (NF-4) - check if the number of substitutions made by gsub() and stored in n matches the number of fields, NF, minus 4 and, if so, print $0.

Also using any awk if you prefer something a bit less cryptic:
$ awk '{ p=2; for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=(i<6?2:1)) { if ($i != $p) { print; next } p=i } }' file
0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/2;11,6        0/0;11,11       0/1;11,6        0/3;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/2;11,6        0/1;11,6      0/2;11,6 0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6        0/1;11,6
0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9        0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10     0/0;10,10        0/1;10,9        0/2;10,11       0/0;10,10       0/0;10,10       0/1;10,9

That just compares the current field starting from 4 with the value of the field 2 fields before it for the fields up to field 6 and 1 before it from then on. If any field does not have the value of it's predecessor then $0 is printed and processing moves on to the next line of input.
